# How can I get multiple pages for a list?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So I'm developing a spigot plugin. It's about friends. If the person does the command to see his friend's list I need to have pages and every page contains 7 friends. The thing is that it's not a friend list with always the same people your friend list changes.

Case I have 10 friends.
I would get 7 friends on the first page and the remaining 3 on the second page.
Case I have 70 friends.
I would have 10 pages.

EDIT: Sorry for confusion. My question is: How can I make it like in the examples. The player does /friend list it shows page 1 with 7 friends or less if he doesn't have 7. Does he have more there will be a second page: /friend list 2. and so on.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's a too wide question. And it's better if you post it on spigot forum instead of stackoverflow

Comment: What you are looking for has a name. Look for 'pagination'

Comment: What is your actual question? You are not actually asking anything. Furthermore, such general questions asking about implementation help are off-topic for StackOverflow, so your question will likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code how to calculate how many pages are necessary. It works 95% of the time, if anyone knows a better solution please edit this as I am also looking to improve this algoritm.

```
int friendsPerPage = 5;
int friendsIHave = 20;

int pages = (friendsIHave / friendsPerPage ) + (friendsIHave % friendsPerPage  == 0 ? 0 : 1);
```

I assume you know how to get the /friends list (LISTHERE). Let's store the LISTHERE into a page variable. Then we can simply print out its contents:

```
int page = ... // you have to make this one
int max = page * friendsPerPage;
int min = max - friendsPerPage;
for(int i = min + 1; i <= max; i++) { // loop through all friends in that page
     // access your friend array here and print it out using "i"
}
```

I hope it'll get you on track!

Answer (score 0):

How you would see the Friends?
As GUI (Inventar) or in the chat?
Code for GUI(not complete):

```
ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<>();
int pages = ((players.size-(players.size()%7))/7)+(players.size()%7 == 0 ? 0 : 1);
ArrayList<String>[] pages = new ArrayList<>()[pages];
int lastpage = 0;
int i = 0;
for(String name : players)
{
     pages[lastpage].add(name);    
     i++;
     if(i == 6){
        i = 0;
        lastpage ++;
    }
}
```

***pages*** is an Array of the pages.
How you Display them is your desicion.

Comment: Thanks for the response I show them in chat. GUI Would be nice but I havent done anything for a gui yet.

Comment: If you liked the answer check it as right may!
I will be gratefull for that thx.
If you woud make a GUI call me at Skype : introtv